# Assign a post to a user in ASP.NET Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-membership

I'm writing a forum in ASP.NET. I have a table of posts. How can I assign a post to a user? If I had a normal User table, I'd just creating a new field in the post table "UserId" and creating an assocation in the Linq to Sql designer. But now? Should I include the aspnet_Users in the designer?

Thanks.

Comment: Yep - I'm writing my own membership system (not a provider)

Comment: Good luck. Did I answer your question satisfactorily?

Answer (score 2):

Including the table in your designer should not be necessary.

Simply define the `UserId` field in your `Posts` table as `uniqueidentifier` and supply the `UserId` when running your queries.

You can get the `Guid` (uniqueidentifier) UserId like this:

```
Guid UserId = (Guid) Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

There is absolutely no need to implement custom providers to facilitate this requirement.

Answer (score -2):

Write your own ASP.NET Membership provider that uses your own database table and spare yourself the hassle of finding out how the MS lays out it's db tables.

I wrote a blog about that some years ago I think:
http://www.tigraine.at/2008/07/08/custom-aspnet-membership-provider/

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry - this is just bad advice.

Comment: I don't see why. You don't need to implement the whole Membership Provider but only the methods relevant to you (namely: login, forgot password and create user) while you are in complete control of the table you are working against. 
Doing weak references into built-in tables without L2S designer support is equally bad advice

Comment: The ASP.NET membership stuff especially falls apart once you have to add per-data permissions at some stage.